# Finite extensions of fields that are algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Consider a finite field extension $K/k$ with $K$ algebraically closed.  The immediate example that comes to mind is $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$, of degree $2$.  Are there any other examples?  Can we construct them of any desired degree $n$?

Motivation: I've recently been studying the Weil restriction of an affine scheme, which requires a finite extension of fields, and because algebraic geometry is cleaner over an algebraically closed field, I'd like one of my fields to be algebraically closed.  Since there are no non-trivial finite extensions of an algebraically closed field, I'm left to find a field that has a finite extension that is algebraically closed.

Comment: @user You should perhaps turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Artin-Schreier Theorem](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf).