# A field extension, the larger field is algebraically closed, are there finite subextensions of arbitrary large degree?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $L/F$ be a field extension of infinite degree. Assume that $L$ is algebraically closed. I am not assuming that $L$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.

Let $d\geq 1$. Must there be an intermediate field $F\subset K \subset L$ such that $K/F$ is finite and of degree at least $d$?

Comment: @user10354138: I forgot to write that $L/F$ is of infinite degree, and added it now. So now it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Let $F$ be algebraically closed and $L=\overline{F(x)}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite extensions of fields that are algebraically closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583827/finite-extensions-of-fields-that-are-algebraically-closed)

Comment: @XanderHenderson: This question is about infinite extensions. I don't think it is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=\Bbb C$ and $F=\overline {\Bbb Q}$. Then an intermediate $K$ cannot be finite over $F$.

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks for the hint - that made me find an even simpler answer