# Fields and cubic extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

i have a question that i do not know how to solve. I am still a beginner in field theory and i want to answer this :

> Does every field $\mathbb{K}$ have a cubic expansion ?

I was thinking about infinite fields and was wondering if they could posses a finite extension but i know that $ \mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{R}$ is an finite extension of degree $2$. But does  $ \mathbb{C}$ have a degree $3$ extension ? Since it is algebraically closed i do not know if it is possible to extend it more.

Even more, to extend $ \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{L}$ with this extension being of degree $3$ i have to find an irreducible polynomial $P$ of degree $3$ that cancels for an algebraic element $x \in \mathbb{L}$. Thus $P$ would be the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and then $ \mathbb{R}/<P>= \mathbb{L}
$ is an extension of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

And i know that such a polynomial exists in characteristic $p$. As we showed in class that there exists at least $1$ irreducible monic polynomial fo any degree $r \geq 1$ over  any finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ a prime number. So if this work even in characteristic $0$ then the statement would be true !

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\mathbb{C}$ (or any algebraically closed field) cannot have an extension of finite degree, since any such extension must necessarily be algebraic. This is proved in many places, including on [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583827/finite-extensions-of-fields-that-are-algebraically-closed).

We can use this to see what goes wrong with your example involving $\mathbb{R}$, but we can also see directly: if you like it is a theorem in real analysis---a basic application of the intermediate value theorem---that every odd degree polynomial over the reals has a real root. So there are no degree $3$ irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$. We can also see this algebraically: if a real polynomial has a complex root $z$ then it must also have the root $\overline{z}$: this means that a real polynomial cannot have an odd number of complex roots, so any hypothetical degree $3$ real polynomial must again have at least one real root. (By "complex roots" here I mean "not purely real", i.e. so that $z \not = \overline{z}$.)